# Find objects not between two objects in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am building a website for car rental, I want to list all available cars on the date user selected.I am posting user date inputs pick up time and drop off time.
For example I have three documents like this.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60845dd9746d1c7a70ca55a6"),
        "carName" : "Peugeot 208",
        "image" : "images/peugeot-208.webp",
        "person" : "4",
        "bags" : "4",
        "gear" : "Manuel",
        "price" : 25,
        "details" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc erat orci, gravida sed accumsan vitae, rutrum sit amet dolor. Suspendisse id diam ut lorem dapibus sollicitudin sit amet non ex. Quisque at euismod purus. Suspendisse gravida sapien ac lectus bibendum congue. Vivamus tempor ipsum id massa pellentesque, nec malesuada nibh fermentum. Cras non gravida ipsum. Mauris mollis malesuada velit ut tempus. Vivamus at velit id quam molestie lacinia. Praesent vel felis sit amet neque consectetur mollis et ut massa. Vivamus efficitur malesuada mollis. Maecenas mauris sem, laoreet eu purus luctus, lobortis maximus massa.",
        "booked" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("60845dd9746d1c7a70ca55a7"),
                        "pickUpDate" : ISODate("2021-04-30T00:00:00Z"),
                        "dropOffDate" : ISODate("2021-05-05T00:00:00Z")
                }
        ],
        "route" : "peugeot-208",
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("60845dd9746d1c7a70ca55a8"),
                        "body" : "Bilmem ne",
                        "date" : "2021-04-23",
                        "name" : "Fiko"
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6084633ba8a1eba43825eca4"),
        "carName" : "Hyundai Accent",
        "image" : "images/hyundai-accent.webp",
        "person" : "4",
        "bags" : "4",
        "gear" : "Manuel",
        "price" : 25,
        "details" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc erat orci, gravida sed accumsan vitae, rutrum sit amet dolor. Suspendisse id diam ut lorem dapibus sollicitudin sit amet non ex. Quisque at euismod purus. Suspendisse gravida sapien ac lectus bibendum congue. Vivamus tempor ipsum id massa pellentesque, nec malesuada nibh fermentum. Cras non gravida ipsum. Mauris mollis malesuada velit ut tempus. Vivamus at velit id quam molestie lacinia. Praesent vel felis sit amet neque consectetur mollis et ut massa. Vivamus efficitur malesuada mollis. Maecenas mauris sem, laoreet eu purus luctus, lobortis maximus massa.",
        "booked" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("6084633ba8a1eba43825eca5"),
                        "pickUpDate" : ISODate("2021-04-23T00:00:00Z"),
                        "dropOffDate" : ISODate("2021-05-01T00:00:00Z")
                }
        ],
        "route" : "hyundai-accent",
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("6084633ba8a1eba43825eca6"),
                        "body" : "Bilmem ne",
                        "date" : "2021-04-23",
                        "name" : "Fiko"
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60846ed9a8a1eba43825eca7"),
        "carName" : "Wolksvagen Polo",
        "image" : "images/polo.png",
        "person" : "4",
        "bags" : "4",
        "gear" : "Manuel",
        "price" : 25,
        "details" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc erat orci, gravida sed accumsan vitae, rutrum sit amet dolor. Suspendisse id diam ut lorem dapibus sollicitudin sit amet non ex. Quisque at euismod purus. Suspendisse gravida sapien ac lectus bibendum congue. Vivamus tempor ipsum id massa pellentesque, nec malesuada nibh fermentum. Cras non gravida ipsum. Mauris mollis malesuada velit ut tempus. Vivamus at velit id quam molestie lacinia. Praesent vel felis sit amet neque consectetur mollis et ut massa. Vivamus efficitur malesuada mollis. Maecenas mauris sem, laoreet eu purus luctus, lobortis maximus massa.",
        "booked" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("60846ed9a8a1eba43825eca8"),
                        "pickUpDate" : ISODate("2021-05-10T00:00:00Z"),
                        "dropOffDate" : ISODate("2021-05-20T00:00:00Z")
                }
        ],
        "route" : "wv-polo",
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("60846ed9a8a1eba43825eca9"),
                        "body" : "Bilmem ne",
                        "date" : "2021-04-23",
                        "name" : "Fiko"
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

When user want to rent a car between from 2021-04-23 to 2021-04-30, I want to show the user just Peugeot 208 because it is the only available car this date range.

I tried to use this

```
db.cardetails.find({'booked' : {$elemMatch : {pickUpDate : {$gte : ISODate('2021-04-23'),$lt : ISODate('2021-04-30')}}}}).pretty()
```

But it is only finds me matching results not the range.

Any help is much appreciated.

First time posting here I might be forget something to mention please let me know any if any information needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the conditions,

- change `$gte` to `$gt`
- change `$lt` to `$lte`

```
db.cardetails.find({
  "booked": {
    $elemMatch: {
      pickUpDate: {
        $gt: ISODate("2021-04-23"),
        $lte: ISODate("2021-04-30")
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/91s79gKb8hx)

Comment: Thank you for a answer,it's not what I want to do but, it helped me to find a solution thank you very much.